# S3 dispatch inside R6 class

Tags: r, r6, r-s3, method-dispatch

I'm trying to see if it is possible to have a S3 dispatch inside an R6 class?
Or maybe I am missing some feature of R6.

Here is the problem I am trying to resolve:

```r
tmp <- R6::R6Class("tmp",
                   list(
                       a = list(x = 1),
                       b = data.frame(x = 1),
                       divide = function(x) UseMethod("divide"),
                       divide.list = function(x) x$x/4,
                       divide.data.frame = function(x) x$x/2,
                       test_list = function() self$divide(self$a),
                       test_df = function() self$divide(self$b)
                   )
                   
)
tmp2 <- tmp$new()
tmp2$test_df()
#> Error in UseMethod("divide"): no applicable method for 'divide' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
tmp2$test_list()
#> Error in UseMethod("divide"): no applicable method for 'divide' applied to an object of class "list"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Solutions need not be S3 dispatch, that just captures the essence of what I am trying to do.

Comment: What is the base `divide` method? It's not base R. (It's not the same as `/`.)

Comment: `divide` is just some pseudo stuff I made up. In reality, I do sampling with `rstan`, and depending on the user's input structure(s), I use different subroutines to reduce the running time. But I then want to summarize them to the same standardized output. But I was imagining having dispatches inside an R6 as a generic programming feature to utilize and process different inputs as well. Of course, I can just do `if (...) {...}  else if ()` etc.

Comment: In essence, my `R6` is (or is quite similar to) a stack data structure with additional features/modeling to run on the data stack.

Answer (score 0):

The dispatching method simply does not find your `S3` implementation **inside** your `R6` class.

It does find it, however, if you define it in the global environment:

```r
tmp <- R6::R6Class("tmp",
                   list(
                       a = list(x = 1),
                       b = data.frame(x = 1),
                       divide = function(x) UseMethod("divide"),
                       test_list = function() self$divide(self$a),
                       test_df = function() self$divide(self$b)
                   )
)

divide.list <- function(x) x$x/4
divide.data.frame <- function(x) x$x/2
tmp2 <- tmp$new()
tmp2$test_df()
# [1] 0.5
tmp2$test_list()
# [1] 0.25
```